Biographies of the Matriarchs
I am looking for a biography of Sarah Immenu, Rivka Immenu, Rachel Immenu and Leah Immenu. I want to give a Drasha dedicated to Sarah next week, an obituary, if you will, and then I might do the same for the rest of the Immahot and either way I am very interested.
Where can I find the most information about their lives, with all the background from Aggada, Midrashim and our Rishonim?
FYI I already have Avraham Avinu, by Chaim Zvi Noyek, which does have a lot of information about Sarah, but I am looking for more.
Do you have any book recommendations, or even a good list of sources for me to look at?
Thanks!

By the way, I know you have mentioned in the past how you are a fan of Rabbi Deutsch's series. He literally just released a new sefer entitled "Let My Nation Begin" centred around Avraham - https://www.feldheim.com/let-my-nation-series+edition-Let~My~Nation~Begin

@Dov whoa great, thank you. Did you come across Avraham Avinu by Noyek? It's great. I want to get Adam, Noach, and eventually he's going to bio Yitzchak and Yaacov too. Must. Get. Them. All!! Also, the rest of the Let My Nation series that I haven't got yet...

A good starting point is a personal fave of mine - Ishei HaTanach: Encyclopedia of Biblical Personalities by Rabbi Yishai Chasida.
It is not a biography but it looks at key features of their life and provides numerous sources.
It has 5 pages worth of sources on Sarah's life and explores:

Her personality
Her Beauty
Her Righteousness
In Pharoah's Palace
With Hagar
Birth of Yitzchak
Death

It has 2.5 pages on Rivka exploring:

Her personality
Her marriage
Her pregnancy
Yaakov's blessing
Death

3 pages on Rochel, exploring:

Personality
Meets Yaakov
Bears Children
Teraphim
Death

2 pages on Leah, exploring:

Personality
Marriage
Children
Death


There is a longer source written in English "The Passions of the Matriarchs" by Shera Aranoff Tuchman and Sandra E. Rapoport. The story of Sarah occupies pp. 3-82 with the following sections:

Introduction to Sarai, Abram's wife
Sarai's Abduction by Pharaoh
G-d promises Sarai a Child and Changes her Name
Sarah's Rejuvenation
Sarah's Abduction by Avimelech
Sarah's pregnancy and birth of Isaac
The children of Sarah and the Handmaiden
Abraham Heeds Sarah's Plea
Sarah is Separated from Isaac: The Akeda
The Death of Sarah
Sarah is Eulogized and Buried in Ma'arat haMakhphela
Epilogue to Sarah

It has similar parts for Rivkah, Leah and Rachel. It is is written for girls and has many interesting sources. I had my struggles with some choices of words in it, so it may need to be revised to be more polished.

Hi, does this have any haskamas? From who? Looks good and those are some very jewish sounding names, but I would like to know up front if it is written by non-orthodox authors, or from a non-orthodox pov

@RabbiKaii The image of the back cover of the book in the link provides "haskamos" from Avivah Zornberg and Rabbi Joseph Telushkin, both quite public Orthodox intellectuals.

@RabbiKaii I must have an older edition , which additionally has back cover "haskamos" from Diane Sharon and R' Haskel Lookstein.

@RabbiKaii It is written from a Modern Orthodox feminist perspective. From the portions of the book that I have read, it seems to adhere fairly closely to mekoros from Chazal and meforshim (which are cited copiously), yet it is also interspersed with the authors' speculation and interpretation of ambiguities in the sources. Altogether, I find it an worthwhile read. On a personal note, one of the authors is a relative of mine who I know to have sterling personal character.
